# skipping form fields values while building json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am sending form values to the Javascript to build a JSON object using this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
```

This function is building a JSON object, but with this it is also building the JSON for the empty values too.

I want that if the form field value is empty, it should skip it overall.

Let me guide please how it will work.

Comment: You don't need to build the JSON object, it's already built-in in your browser.

Comment: $(this).serialize() should be sufficient if this here refers to your form object.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will Help !

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var o = {};
  this.filter(function(){
    if(this.value != "")
        o[this.name] = this.value;
  }); 
 return JSON.stringify(o);
};
```

You can also view result in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ryuegjuL. Let me know for any further help.